# How to remove element from array which is property of object

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects like this:

```
const array = [
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 25,
    cars: ["bmw", "tesla", "ford", "honda"]
  },
  ...other objects
]
```

So, how can I remove elements in property cars, like if I could get element "ford" and delete it, then my object will be like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: 25, 
    cars: ["bmw", "tesla", "honda"]
  },
  ...other objects
]
```

Comment: Asking how to remove an element from an array means, you didn't do any research. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array). In you case it's array of object so `array[0]['cars']` and apply method on this.

Answer (score 3):

Simply `.map()` your array and `.filter()` every item's car property to remove `"ford"`.

```js
const array = [{
    name: "Jack",
    age: 25,
    cars: ["bmw", "tesla", "ford", "honda"]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 25,
    cars: ["bmw", "tesla", "ford", "honda"]
  },
]

const result = array.map((item) => ({ ...item,
  cars: item.cars.filter(car => car !== "ford")
}));
console.log(result)
```